# How do I make a directive's functions globally available?

Tags: angularjs

Imagine I have a singleton user-interface element that I want to provide services to the entire application.

The following "works", in that `setMessage()` is available anywhere in the application, via $rootScope:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.17/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<script>
angular.module('myApp', [])
.directive('myDirective',  function($rootScope) {
  return {
    scope : {},
    template: '<div>Status: {{contents}}</div>',
    controller: function($scope) {
      $rootScope.setMessage = function(contents) {
        $scope.contents = contents;
      };
    }
  };
});
</script>
<div my-directive=""></div>
<button ng-click="setMessage('clicked')">Click Me</button>
</body> </html>
```

It works, but I don't like it.  It just doesn't feel anglish to me.  I have been toying with the idea of create a service that exports a function to set the value and another function to get it, but that doesn't smell much better.

Any suggestions?

Comment: as you said, a service is the typical way to share data across multiple directives or controllers. It seems much better than putting things on the root scope and would be easy to test.

Comment: Services are the way to go

Comment: Angular services are substitutable objects that are wired together using dependency injection (DI). You can use services to organize and share code across your app.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services